# How to remove a tooltip from a pagination component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I don't know how to remove tooltip from a pagination element. I'm using antd's table. This table contains a pagination. It's a part of the table. I'm trying to customize it using styled-components library. I've tried to find all classes which is containing tooltip in their titles and set them:

```
display: none !important;
```

But there was no result. There should be some class that is used for this purpose which I have no idea.

I will be grateful if someone knows the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip comes from the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) of `<li/>` elements.

[image]

Such behavior is by design, therefore **you can't remove it**.

Alternative solutions which aren't recommended:

- Implement `Pagination` by yourself, style it using the `antd-css` classes and integrate it with your custom `Table`.
- Dynamically remove all `title` attributes by querying the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Add `showTitle=false` in pagination, just put this...

```
pagination={{...pagination, <b>showTitle: false</b>}}
```

OR

```
pagination={<b>showTitle: false</b>}
```

It will disable tooltip in pagination.

My code Image:

[image: My code Image]

And site API image:

[image: site API image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Pagination />` component and `showTitle` prop with `false` value.